# Find and replace in N++

Tags: regex, notepad++, find-replace

I have a N++ file with the following lines:

```
asm-java-2.0.0-lib  
cib-slides-3.1.0  
lib-hibernate-common-4.0.0-beta
```

I want to remove everything from the '-' before the numbers begin so the results look like:

```
asm-java  
cib-slides  
lib-hibernate-common
```

So far I've come up with `[0-9]+` but that ignores the `'.'` and the trailing alphabets. Does anyone know a correct command for find and replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `-\d.*$`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
-       # a dash
\d      # a digit
.*      # 0 or more any character but newline
$       # end of line
```

**Result for given example:**

```
asm-java
cib-slides
lib-hibernate-common
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regex to find and replace

Find: ^(.+)-\d.*$

Replace: $1

Answer (score 1):

Here's regex I used in `VSCode` to find and replace to get your task done:

```
(.*)?-\d.*
```

And replace with `$1`
Not sure about notepad++ but should get it done for you as well.